# how to get value in this type of object in angular

Tags: angular

ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)} __zone_symbol__state : true __zone_symbol__value : 3 Symbol(Symbol.species) : (...) Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag) : (...) [[Prototype]] : Object}

get value in object

[image: angular image code]

Comment: Which code given Zone object? please share it as well.

Comment: ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}
__zone_symbol__state
: 
true
__zone_symbol__value
: 
3
Symbol(Symbol.species)
: 
(...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag)
: 
(...)
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object   in angular 14 and I will get value of 3

Comment: I mean Angular code.

Comment: yes this is angular code

Comment: Are you sure? Because this is look like promise object.

Comment: actually i used stripe payment method and I got return value of this type object so ...    ok it is promise object how to I get value that?

Comment: Can you please share piece of code that return this type of object?

Comment: this.tnk= payWithCard(GetStripeValue, getCardValue, getSplicedData,a)
             function payWithCard(stripe: any, card: any, clientSecret: any,step:any) {
             return stripe
                .confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
                  payment_method: {
                    card: card,
                    billing_details: {
                      name: bookingForm.value.Card_name,

Comment: address: {
                        postal_code: bookingForm.value.PostCodePayment
                      }
                    }
                  },
                })
                .then(function (result: any) {
                  if (result.error) {
                    showError(result.error.message);
                  }
                  else {
                   
                    orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id);
                      step=3;
                  }

Comment: return step;
                });
            };

            console.log(this.tnk);

Comment: Can you please update your question with above code?

Comment: update the code of image  and tag name is angular  image code

Answer (score 0):

You need to try below:

```
function payWithCard(stripe: any, card: any, clientSecret: any,step:any) { 
  return stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, { 
    payment_method: { card: card, billing_details: { name: bookingForm.value.Card_name, address: { postal_code: bookingForm.value.PostCodePayment } } }, 
  }).then(function (result: any) { 
    if (result.error) {
     showError(result.error.message); 
    } else { 
      orderComplete(result.paymentIntent.id); 
      step = 3; 
    }
    this.tnk = step;
  }); 
}; 

payWithCard(GetStripeValue, getCardValue, getSplicedData,a);
console.log(this.tnk);
```

Comment: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation. i got this type of error because this function not accept the global variable like this.tnk

Comment: actually i need step value in out of function that I use return method if u have know any other way to get step value in function plz mention it!